# R gmm package use for prediction

Tags: r, gmm

I wish to try the R gmm algorithm to predict.

Question #1: is it possible to use gmm to predict? (the word "predict" does not appear in the [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmm/gmm.pdf))

Question #2: if it is possible to do prediction with gmm, how does one do it?

I am looking for the simplest example; for example using svm would be done with:

```
model <- svm(train, trainLabels)
testpred <- predict(model, test)
```

Question #3:
I cannot even reproduce the examples mentioned in the [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmm/gmm.pdf).
Page 24 shows the code:

```
## CAPM test with GMM
data(Finance)
r <- Finance[1:300, 1:10]
rm <- Finance[1:300, "rm"]
rf <- Finance[1:300, "rf"]
z <- as.matrix(r-rf)
t <- nrow(z)
zm <- rm-rf
h <- matrix(zm, t, 1)
res <- gmm(z ~ zm, x = h)
summary(res)
```

but even after installing the package `gmm`, R does not know the data `Finance`.

```
> data(Finance)
Warning message:
In data(Finance) : data set ‘Finance’ not found
```

What am I missing?

Comment: concerning question 3: it works for me. Did you load the package gmm first? This would be done with `library(gmm)` before `## CAPM test with GMM
data(Finance)...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need the following commands at the top

```
library(gmm)
data(Finance)
```